# AWS SDK vs AWS CLI - AWS Cloud Formation - Terraform

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, terraform, aws-cli

For provisioning infrastructure in AWS cloud, we are currently using Cloud formation templates invoked from ansible roles, but we see that after increasing the size of infrastructure, this code has become unstructured or not modularised in GitHub

Github has spaghetti of this code with no proper structure, less readable, not easily picked by new technician

Specifically for provisioning infrastructure, I see that maintaining code written in  *domain specific languages* like ansible, terraform, cloudformation etc... is not a good idea for long term maintenance of code in GitHub, because for complete(full) automation, you use combination of these TECHNOLOGIES.

Philosophy is, the aws sdk code looks more structured in GitHub because it gives lot of abstraction hiding implementation details.

Of course *provisioning code* is as important as *functional code* that runs on that provisioned infrastructure.

We are confident that, after moving from Azure, that we will stick to AWS cloud

---

domain specific language vis-a-vis programming language,

Does aws sdk approach resolve this problem? We prefer GoLang aws  sdk so that any GoLang programmer can pick it up..

Comment: What about terraform?

Comment: @Ntwobike terraform is cloud agnostic version of cloudformation... please read the query

Comment: Cloud agnostic is only one thing there are other differences, for ex: you can use the module system which doesn't have in the CF(stackstes yes but not the same) however you question is not about CF or TF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are stating that due to an increase in size your Cloud Formation code has become unmanageable, and are now interested in defining it using the AWS SDK so you can use software best practices to keep the code more maintainable.

The downside of the AWS SDK as opposed to a declarative language is that now you are responsible for ensuring that when you click run it will not just create a new instance. E.g. when I deploy an ec2 machine via the AWS SDK, the next time I run that code it will deploy a new ec2 machine. Cloud Formation maintains a state of what has been deployed where so it is easier to deploy incremental changes to the infrastructure and revert changes.

What I would recommend you to check out is the new [AWS-CDK](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk) which allows you to define code that eventually is run via Cloud Formation. It allows you to write OO style objects :

```
const vpc = new Vpc(this, 'vpc', {
            cidr: '10.150.0.0/16',
            natGateways: 2,
            subnetConfiguration: [
                {
                    name: 'Public',
                    subnetType: SubnetType.Public,
                    cidrMask: 20
                },
                {
                    name: 'Private',
                    subnetType: SubnetType.Private,
                    cidrMask: 22
                },
                {
                    name: 'Isolated',
                    subnetType: SubnetType.Isolated,
                    cidrMask: 22
                }
            ]
        });
```

Sadly Golang is not supported yet.

Comment: How soon, GoLang support can go with aws cdk? Is there a aws forum, where I can seek the answer?

Comment: I think maintaining state is also difficult with terraform. Isn't it?

Comment: Supplementary... do you suggest software best practice for configuration? Ansible is what we use now

Comment: I am not sure on the roadmap of the AWS-CDK and I am unsure if that is publicly available. You could check on their Gitter or file an issue on Github. In my current situation I don't really have to deal with software configuration as we are running on top of AWS EKS. We are not manually setting up VMs that need to be configured so I can't help in that regard. Maintaining state is in terraform is not difficult, you can easily setup an S3 bucket to maintain the state. The harder part is achieving CI/CD like cloud formation, although that is possible as well. Terraform is cloud-agnostic though.

Comment: You mean cloud formation enables CI/CD unlike terraform? In the sense..... cloudformation can go with functional code... and be part of jenkins build?

Comment: No, as in Cloud Formation provides CI/CD because AWS runs your Cloud Formation once you deploy it. Terraform is something you would deploy yourself (or most likely as part of a Jenkins build) but you do not have a managed CD pipeline like AWS cloud formation does. There are a lot of open source projects that help with this though.

Comment: When you say CloudFormation remembers the state? Let us say, if I create root CA certificate using AWS Certification mgr using [CloudFormation template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-certificatemanager-certificate.html), does Cloud Formation remember the state? so that running that template again will not create another root CA certificate.

Comment: Can you refer me to the projects that you mentioned about?

Comment: Yes when running the CloudFormation template it will not create the CA again when rerunning. You can check out for example: https://www.runatlantis.io/ in regards to Terraform CI/CD

Comment: So, To handle state issues,  I need to use aws_cdk instead of aws_sdk or AWS_CLI+ansible

Comment: Yes, either the CDK or Cloud Formation, otherwise you will become responsible for maintaining the state.

Comment: Is CDK ready to use? Because I see from this [discussion](https://youtu.be/Lh-kVC2r2AU), there are more changes required...

Comment: I mean, we use Cloud formation templates to create every type of aws resource(CA/EC2/ELB/...). Is CDK equally powerful in creating all these resources?

Comment: If you check the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-construct-library.html you see that most resources are supported